# How to make a transparent form with a semi-transparent PNG in .NET?

Tags: .net, transparency

I'm trying to make a little prank program which would emulate a "broken screen" by drawing a PNG overlay onto it. I'm trying to do it with Windows Forms (since it's what I'm most familiar with), but so far - no luck. I can make the form transparent by the `TransparencyKey`/`BackgroundColor` trick, but it predictably falls apart when the PNG needs to be drawn. Any other ideas?

**Update:**

To clarify, I want this:

[Right http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedRight.jpg](http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedRight.jpg)

But currently I'm only getting this:

[Wrong http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedWrong.jpg](http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedWrong.jpg)

**Update2:** I got the overlay image from [DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/window7/art/Broken-Screen-Overlay-162224514) via Google search:

[image: Overlay]

Comment: Can you provide the actual image so others can try it themselves?

Comment: The PNG can't have any transparency.  It is transparent against the form's BackColor, your TransparencyKey.  Which is why you see green, it no longer matches the key.  Make the key something close to white and it will look better, but not perfect.  Another way to do it is to make a screenshot of the background, now it is perfect as long as the background is static.

Comment: @HansPassant - Is there truly no way to make this effect? I'm not tied to Windows Forms - WPF is an option too. I'm unfamiliar with it, but still. And I've read somewhere that it offers such an option (although it should use the standard WinAPI underneath anyway, so at least in theory it should be possible in WinForms too).

Comment: I gave pretty specific hints, you'll need to try them.  This is otherwise a possible reason that you don't see a lot of other apps display bullet holes in their main window.

Comment: @HansPassant - The only two things that you mentioned is about `TransparencyKey` needing to mach perfectly (which I knew already, if you read my post carefully), and about making a screenshot of the background (which is another idea that I know of, but due to it's obvious imperfections I explicitly asked for true transparency). I've finally found other articles mentioning `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `UpdateLayeredWindow`, which seem to be a step in the right direction. I will give those a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want exactly but, you may draw the full opaque PNG, than you may set the opacity property of the form to %75 for instance.

EDIT: If the answer above is not what you wanted, you may create a PictureBox with Transparent background, set it's dock to fill and don't bring that control to front. When you want to display image you will bring it to front. Than set the opacity of your image(if needed) by:

```
   Public Function SetImgOpacity(ByRef imgPic As Image, ByVal imgOpac As Single) As Image

    Dim bmpPic As New Bitmap(imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height)
    Dim gfxPic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPic)
    Dim cmxPic As New ColorMatrix()
    Dim iaPic As New ImageAttributes()

    cmxPic.Matrix33 = imgOpac

    iaPic.SetColorMatrix(cmxPic, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
    gfxPic.DrawImage(imgPic, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height), 0, 0, imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, iaPic)

    gfxPic.Dispose()
    iaPic.Dispose()

    Return bmpPic

    End Function
```

Now you may set the PictureBox's Image to your new half-transparent image.

EDIT 2: Here is a good trick

make your form invisible and with a timer use this where "a" in resources is your image:

```
    Dim x As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
    x.DrawImage(My.Resources.a, 0, 0)
```

You can draw on screen without a form. However, you need to draw continuously since any other drawing may break your illusion.

Comment: The PNG has areas ranging from fully transparent to fully opaque and anywhere inbetween.

Comment: You do not seem to have understood the problem. The problem is that TransparencyKey allows only **one** color to be transparent in the entire form (along with all of its PictureBox'es and whatnotelse). But I need a full range of semi-transparent colors. In other words, with TransparencyKey I only get [this](http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedWrong.jpg) while I want [this](http://valts.21.lv/problem/CrackedRight.jpg).

Comment: I know of this trick, and tried to use it, like 10 years ago, only to find that it has a serious drawback - pretty often software caches the contents of a window when it's being moved or scrolled, and that then caches my overlay too. The result is not pretty. It's an option, true, but I figured that with the great new technology feats in Windows XP and above (I actually want to run it on a WinXP machine) there should be a neater solution.